# Hide credentials in package development in R

Tags: r, security, credentials, package-development

I'm developing a package for my company, and I want to need to hide the credentials of the connections to redshift databases.
Is there an easy way to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create a file `my_credentials.env`
2. At the beginning of the code run `readRenviron("my_credentials.env")`
3. Access your variables by `Sys.getenv("MY_VARIABLE")`

More information over here [basic](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRenviron.html) or [advanced](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html)